# indexing names in a std::vector

Tags: c++

I made a program that lets you enter your name and outputs it.
I can't find a way to index my names. For example, if you enter "John, Jason, Jam", you would get the names numbered like so: "1:John, 2:Jason, 3:Jam"

```
int main()
{
    vector<string> names; 

    names.push_back(read_string("Enter a name: ")); 
    names.push_back(read_string("Enter a name: ")); 
    names.push_back(read_string("Enter a name: ")); 

    for(int  i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
    {
            write_line( names[i]);
    }

    int total;
    total = total_length(names);

    write("Total length: ");
    write_line(total);

    bool has_John; 
    has_John = contains(names, "John");

    if ( has_John ) write_line("Contain's John");


    write_line(shortest_name(names));


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: in your `for` loop, `i` is already the index of the name in the vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
 for(int  i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
{
        write_line( (i+1) +names[i]);
}
```